# ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 : PDF to JPG including crop to bounding box

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

PDFs that were used as source for printed media usually contain a bounding box with instructions for the printing facilities. If you open a PDF in a normal PDF Viewer, you don't see that extra white space around the page.

However if you use ImageMagick to convert a PDF (containing bounding box) to JPG, the JPG contains the white border.

How do you get rid of this bounding box?

Just as a hint: If you open a PDF in Adobe Photoshop you can choose the option "Crop to Bounding Box", that option I would like to use in ImageMagick but don't know how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ImageMagick has two options that allow you to use the CropBox or the TrimBox of your PDF document. I am not sure which one is the same as the bouding box in photoshop but you can use it like this:

```
convert -define pdf:use-cropbox=true -density 300 input.pdf output.jpg
convert -define pdf:use-trimbox=true -density 300 input.pdf output.jpg
```

Other PDF specific options can be found here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php (scroll down to PDF)

Comment: I will try this option tomorrow and if it works I'll give it a +1. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: In my case `-define pdf:use-cropbox=true` worked well